Redis Hierarchical data storage
I have a data in below format

Country (Root Object)

State

City
Each Country, State and City has an Id assigned to it.





Country has CountryID
State has StatueID
City has CityID
API which is connected to the ScyllaDB has the below Usecases
Api which connects to redis has below usecases
If user requests CityID, he has to get StateID and CountryID (All parent Ids)
If user requests CountryID, he has to get all StateIDs and CityIDs (All child Ids)
Question
What is the best way to store and retrieve this data in redis?

Sounds like a job for RedisJSON.

... Which is part of Redis Stack redis.io
